# How to get dimensions of only DisplayObjectContainer's *visible* contents?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

A `DisplayObjectContainer`'s dimensions change based on its contents.

That can be a LOT of contents, many of them with `visible = false` or masked, thus making them hidden. Is there a way to get only the *visible* contents of a `DisplayObjectContainer` similar to a `TextField` has the `textHeight` property, which gives you the exact dimension of what you see on-screen.

Comment: A display object with no contents would have a height of zero and a width of zero.

Comment: I believe this is a poorly stated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [this article](http://www.insideria.com/2008/11/visible-false-versus-removechi.html), Colin Moock states that there is no such property for getting the "visible width" of a DisplayObjectContainer. That article does go into detail on the other ways of hiding an object, though, and it's well worth reading.

However, Moock later came up with a workaround: some code to check the actual visible pixels of an object and return the width & height based on that. This deals with masked objects, as well as objects with .visible set to false. His code is available [here](http://www.moock.org/blog/archives/000292.html).

Answer (score -1):

If it's a loaded object you can get the metadata width/height via `loader.contentLoaderInfo.width` etc.

Comment: FYI this was the answer to the first 'revision' of the question, I reckon it doesn't make any sense anymore too. but still not nice to down score it for that :P